# How to make a polygon radar (spider) chart in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, web-crawler

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

labels=['Siege', 'Initiation', 'Crowd_control', 'Wave_clear', 'Objective_damage']
markers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
str_markers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

def make_radar_chart(name, stats, attribute_labels=labels,
                     plot_markers=markers, plot_str_markers=str_markers):

    labels = np.array(attribute_labels)

    angles = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, len(labels), endpoint=False)
    stats = np.concatenate((stats,[stats[0]]))
    angles = np.concatenate((angles,[angles[0]]))

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
    ax.plot(angles, stats, 'o-', linewidth=2)
    ax.fill(angles, stats, alpha=0.25)
    ax.set_thetagrids(angles * 180/np.pi, labels)
    plt.yticks(markers)
    ax.set_title(name)
    ax.grid(True)

    fig.savefig("static/images/%s.png" % name)

    return plt.show()

make_radar_chart("Agni", [2,3,4,4,5]) # example
```

[image]

[image]

Basically I want the chart to be a pentagon instead of circle. Can anyone help with this. I am using python matplotlib to save an image which will stored and displayed later. I want my chart to have the form of the second picture

EDIT:

```
    gridlines = ax.yaxis.get_gridlines()
    for gl in gridlines:
        gl.get_path()._interpolation_steps = 5
```

adding this section of code from answer below helped a lot. I am getting this chart. Still need to figure out how to get rid of the outer most ring: [image]

Comment: While it's not impossible I'm not sure there's an easy built-in way to do this. See [the radar chart demo](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/radar_chart.html) in the pyplot documentation.

Comment: I looked at this before and could not figure out how to implement their solution

Comment: If the code shown produces the image shown, what exactly is the question? In how far is this not what you want?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest "*Basically I want the chart to be a pentagon instead of circle.*". Also the "polygon" in the title. I believe the question is clear and OP needs the demo I linked.

Comment: updated question to provide second img as template of what im looking to make

Comment: Ah, so the problem is that the grid lines are circular.

Comment: And in particular the tangential axis.

Comment: For the outer Spines the demo shows how to do it. Why not use it?

Comment: im working on it I have not figured the solution out yet

Comment: Copy the code from my answer. Replace the data with your own data and run the example. There isn't really anything that can go wrong.

Comment: how can i rotate the `labels ` ?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce this with matplotlib 3.3 or higher. The circles are still there. Is there any other way around?

Comment: Did anyone figure out how to do this on matplotlib 3.3 or higher? I'm deep inside matplotlib source code, but haven't yet figured it out

Answer (score 22):

The [radar chart demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/specialty_plots/radar_chart.html) shows how to make the a radar chart. The result looks like this:

[image]

Here, the outer spine is polygon shaped as desired. However the inner grid lines are circular. 
So the open question is how to make the gridlines the same shape as the spines.

This can be done by overriding the `draw` method and setting the gridlines' path interpolation step variable to the number of variables of the `RadarAxes` class.

```
gridlines = self.yaxis.get_gridlines()
for gl in gridlines:
    gl.get_path()._interpolation_steps = num_vars
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, RegularPolygon
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.projections.polar import PolarAxes
from matplotlib.projections import register_projection
from matplotlib.spines import Spine
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D


def radar_factory(num_vars, frame='circle'):
    """Create a radar chart with `num_vars` axes.

    This function creates a RadarAxes projection and registers it.

    Parameters
    ----------
    num_vars : int
        Number of variables for radar chart.
    frame : {'circle' | 'polygon'}
        Shape of frame surrounding axes.

    """
    # calculate evenly-spaced axis angles
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num_vars, endpoint=False)

    class RadarAxes(PolarAxes):

        name = 'radar'

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            # rotate plot such that the first axis is at the top
            self.set_theta_zero_location('N')

        def fill(self, *args, closed=True, **kwargs):
            """Override fill so that line is closed by default"""
            return super().fill(closed=closed, *args, **kwargs)

        def plot(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """Override plot so that line is closed by default"""
            lines = super().plot(*args, **kwargs)
            for line in lines:
                self._close_line(line)

        def _close_line(self, line):
            x, y = line.get_data()
            # FIXME: markers at x[0], y[0] get doubled-up
            if x[0] != x[-1]:
                x = np.concatenate((x, [x[0]]))
                y = np.concatenate((y, [y[0]]))
                line.set_data(x, y)

        def set_varlabels(self, labels):
            self.set_thetagrids(np.degrees(theta), labels)

        def _gen_axes_patch(self):
            # The Axes patch must be centered at (0.5, 0.5) and of radius 0.5
            # in axes coordinates.
            if frame == 'circle':
                return Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.5)
            elif frame == 'polygon':
                return RegularPolygon((0.5, 0.5), num_vars,
                                      radius=.5, edgecolor="k")
            else:
                raise ValueError("unknown value for 'frame': %s" % frame)

        def draw(self, renderer):
            """ Draw. If frame is polygon, make gridlines polygon-shaped """
            if frame == 'polygon':
                gridlines = self.yaxis.get_gridlines()
                for gl in gridlines:
                    gl.get_path()._interpolation_steps = num_vars
            super().draw(renderer)


        def _gen_axes_spines(self):
            if frame == 'circle':
                return super()._gen_axes_spines()
            elif frame == 'polygon':
                # spine_type must be 'left'/'right'/'top'/'bottom'/'circle'.
                spine = Spine(axes=self,
                              spine_type='circle',
                              path=Path.unit_regular_polygon(num_vars))
                # unit_regular_polygon gives a polygon of radius 1 centered at
                # (0, 0) but we want a polygon of radius 0.5 centered at (0.5,
                # 0.5) in axes coordinates.
                spine.set_transform(Affine2D().scale(.5).translate(.5, .5)
                                    + self.transAxes)


                return {'polar': spine}
            else:
                raise ValueError("unknown value for 'frame': %s" % frame)

    register_projection(RadarAxes)
    return theta


data = [['Sulfate', 'Nitrate', 'EC', 'OC1', 'OC2', 'OC3', 'OP', 'CO', 'O3'],
        ('Basecase', [
            [0.88, 0.01, 0.03, 0.03, 0.00, 0.06, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.07, 0.95, 0.04, 0.05, 0.00, 0.02, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.02, 0.85, 0.19, 0.05, 0.10, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.02, 0.01, 0.07, 0.01, 0.21, 0.12, 0.98, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.71, 0.74, 0.70, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]])]

N = len(data[0])
theta = radar_factory(N, frame='polygon')

spoke_labels = data.pop(0)
title, case_data = data[0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6), subplot_kw=dict(projection='radar'))
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85, bottom=0.05)

ax.set_rgrids([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8])
ax.set_title(title,  position=(0.5, 1.1), ha='center')

for d in case_data:
    line = ax.plot(theta, d)
    ax.fill(theta, d,  alpha=0.25)
ax.set_varlabels(spoke_labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How can I rotate the labels so that `CO` (0 degrees) replaces `Sulfate` (at 90 degrees)?

Comment: the demo and this code gives me a syntax error for this line  `def fill(self, *args, closed=True, **kwargs):` in both python 2 and 3.  What am I missing?

Comment: How can I know what's missing? The example works fine as it is.

Comment: When you set the maximum grid value to 0.8, and the maximum value to in the data to 0.8, you can see that the line is not drawn in the corner.  How can I fix this? It seems to be a matplotlib thing though ....

Comment: Matplotlib uses a 5% margin by default. You can change that if you want, or set the limits manually.

Comment: While the chart works brilliantly and is almost exactly what I need, I just have a small question, if its possible to add a small dropdown and show only the plotlines for the value selected in the dropdown?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65514398/how-to-make-radar-spider-chart-with-pentagon-grid-using-matplotlib-and-python?noredirect=1&lq=1
this doesn't work in matplotlib>=3.3.3. You need to downgrade to 3.2.2

Comment: THat function is very useful but there is no way to update the radar chart changing the number of radial axes. You have to remove the charth and create it again.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65514398/how-to-make-radar-spider-chart-with-pentagon-grid-using-matplotlib-and-python?noredirect=1&lq=1) the answer from @ImportanceOfBeingErnest doesn't work in matplotlib>3.2.2 in that you get circular grids. As shown in this [PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/22458/files) you can use the following

```py
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, RegularPolygon
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.projections.polar import PolarAxes
from matplotlib.projections import register_projection
from matplotlib.spines import Spine
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D


def radar_factory(num_vars, frame='circle'):
    """Create a radar chart with `num_vars` axes.

    This function creates a RadarAxes projection and registers it.

    Parameters
    ----------
    num_vars : int
        Number of variables for radar chart.
    frame : {'circle' | 'polygon'}
        Shape of frame surrounding axes.

    """
    # calculate evenly-spaced axis angles
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num_vars, endpoint=False)
    
    class RadarTransform(PolarAxes.PolarTransform):
        def transform_path_non_affine(self, path):
            # Paths with non-unit interpolation steps correspond to gridlines,
            # in which case we force interpolation (to defeat PolarTransform's
            # autoconversion to circular arcs).
            if path._interpolation_steps > 1:
                path = path.interpolated(num_vars)
            return Path(self.transform(path.vertices), path.codes)

    class RadarAxes(PolarAxes):

        name = 'radar'
        
        PolarTransform = RadarTransform

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            # rotate plot such that the first axis is at the top
            self.set_theta_zero_location('N')

        def fill(self, *args, closed=True, **kwargs):
            """Override fill so that line is closed by default"""
            return super().fill(closed=closed, *args, **kwargs)

        def plot(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """Override plot so that line is closed by default"""
            lines = super().plot(*args, **kwargs)
            for line in lines:
                self._close_line(line)

        def _close_line(self, line):
            x, y = line.get_data()
            # FIXME: markers at x[0], y[0] get doubled-up
            if x[0] != x[-1]:
                x = np.concatenate((x, [x[0]]))
                y = np.concatenate((y, [y[0]]))
                line.set_data(x, y)

        def set_varlabels(self, labels):
            self.set_thetagrids(np.degrees(theta), labels)

        def _gen_axes_patch(self):
            # The Axes patch must be centered at (0.5, 0.5) and of radius 0.5
            # in axes coordinates.
            if frame == 'circle':
                return Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.5)
            elif frame == 'polygon':
                return RegularPolygon((0.5, 0.5), num_vars,
                                      radius=.5, edgecolor="k")
            else:
                raise ValueError("unknown value for 'frame': %s" % frame)

        def draw(self, renderer):
            """ Draw. If frame is polygon, make gridlines polygon-shaped """
            if frame == 'polygon':
                gridlines = self.yaxis.get_gridlines()
                for gl in gridlines:
                    gl.get_path()._interpolation_steps = num_vars
            super().draw(renderer)


        def _gen_axes_spines(self):
            if frame == 'circle':
                return super()._gen_axes_spines()
            elif frame == 'polygon':
                # spine_type must be 'left'/'right'/'top'/'bottom'/'circle'.
                spine = Spine(axes=self,
                              spine_type='circle',
                              path=Path.unit_regular_polygon(num_vars))
                # unit_regular_polygon gives a polygon of radius 1 centered at
                # (0, 0) but we want a polygon of radius 0.5 centered at (0.5,
                # 0.5) in axes coordinates.
                spine.set_transform(Affine2D().scale(.5).translate(.5, .5)
                                    + self.transAxes)


                return {'polar': spine}
            else:
                raise ValueError("unknown value for 'frame': %s" % frame)

    register_projection(RadarAxes)
    return theta


data = [['Sulfate', 'Nitrate', 'EC', 'OC1', 'OC2', 'OC3', 'OP', 'CO', 'O3'],
        ('Basecase', [
            [0.88, 0.01, 0.03, 0.03, 0.00, 0.06, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.07, 0.95, 0.04, 0.05, 0.00, 0.02, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.02, 0.85, 0.19, 0.05, 0.10, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.02, 0.01, 0.07, 0.01, 0.21, 0.12, 0.98, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.71, 0.74, 0.70, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]])]

N = len(data[0])
theta = radar_factory(N, frame='polygon')

spoke_labels = data.pop(0)
title, case_data = data[0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6), subplot_kw=dict(projection='radar'))
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85, bottom=0.05)

ax.set_rgrids([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8])
ax.set_title(title,  position=(0.5, 1.1), ha='center')

for d in case_data:
    line = ax.plot(theta, d)
    ax.fill(theta, d, alpha=0.25, label='_nolegend_')
ax.set_varlabels(spoke_labels)

plt.show()
```

to get the desired:

[image]