# How to make radar spider chart with pentagon grid using matplotlib and python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, radar-chart

I have a radar chart. Need to change the grid from circle-form to pentagon-form. Currently, I have this output:

[image]

Whereas I expect smth like this:

[image]

Here's the info about the system i have: Windows 10 (64-bit); Python - 3.8.0 (32-bit); matplotlib - 3.3.3.
This question i've seen here: [How to make a polygon radar (spider) chart in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910187/how-to-make-a-polygon-radar-spider-chart-in-python) but it doesn't resolve my question.
But it doesn't work for me and i can't understand why. I can simply copy the code, but the result is - outer border changes to pentagon-form, but the inner gridlines remain circular. But it works for other people!

The code of the program is below:

```py
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, RegularPolygon
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.projections.polar import PolarAxes
from matplotlib.projections import register_projection
from matplotlib.spines import Spine
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D


def radar_factory(num_vars, frame='circle'):
    """Create a radar chart with `num_vars` axes.

    This function creates a RadarAxes projection and registers it.

    Parameters
    ----------
    num_vars : int
        Number of variables for radar chart.
    frame : {'circle' | 'polygon'}
        Shape of frame surrounding axes.

    """
    # calculate evenly-spaced axis angles
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num_vars, endpoint=False)

    class RadarAxes(PolarAxes):

        name = 'radar'

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            # rotate plot such that the first axis is at the top
            self.set_theta_zero_location('N')

        def fill(self, *args, closed=True, **kwargs):
            """Override fill so that line is closed by default"""
            return super().fill(closed=closed, *args, **kwargs)

        def plot(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """Override plot so that line is closed by default"""
            lines = super().plot(*args, **kwargs)
            for line in lines:
                self._close_line(line)

        def _close_line(self, line):
            x, y = line.get_data()
            # FIXME: markers at x[0], y[0] get doubled-up
            if x[0] != x[-1]:
                x = np.concatenate((x, [x[0]]))
                y = np.concatenate((y, [y[0]]))
                line.set_data(x, y)

        def set_varlabels(self, labels):
            self.set_thetagrids(np.degrees(theta), labels)

        def _gen_axes_patch(self):
            # The Axes patch must be centered at (0.5, 0.5) and of radius 0.5
            # in axes coordinates.
            if frame == 'circle':
                return Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.5)
            elif frame == 'polygon':
                return RegularPolygon((0.5, 0.5), num_vars, radius=0.5, edgecolor="k")
            else:
                raise ValueError("unknown value for 'frame': %s" % frame)

        def draw(self, renderer):
            """ Draw. If frame is polygon, make gridlines polygon-shaped """
            if frame == 'polygon':
                gridlines = self.yaxis.get_gridlines()
                for gl in gridlines:
                    gl.get_path()._interpolation_steps = num_vars
            super().draw(renderer)

        def _gen_axes_spines(self):
            if frame == 'circle':
                return super()._gen_axes_spines()
            elif frame == 'polygon':
                # spine_type must be 'left'/'right'/'top'/'bottom'/'circle'.
                spine = Spine(axes=self,
                              spine_type='circle',
                              path=Path.unit_regular_polygon(num_vars))
                # unit_regular_polygon gives a polygon of radius 1 centered at
                # (0, 0) but we want a polygon of radius 0.5 centered at (0.5,
                # 0.5) in axes coordinates.
                spine.set_transform(Affine2D().scale(.5).translate(.5, .5)
                                    + self.transAxes)
                return {'polar': spine}
            else:
                raise ValueError("unknown value for 'frame': %s" % frame)

    register_projection(RadarAxes)
    return theta


data = [['O1', 'O2', 'O3', 'O4', 'O5'],
        ('Title', [
                    [4, 3.5, 4, 2, 3,], 
                    [1.07, 5.95, 2.04, 1.05, 0.00,], 
                  ]
        )]

N = len(data[0])
theta = radar_factory(N, frame='polygon')                                     # polygon  !!!

spoke_labels = data.pop(0)
title, case_data = data[0]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5), subplot_kw=dict(projection='radar'))
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85, bottom=0.05)
ax.set_rgrids([0, 1, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6])
ax.set_title(title,  position=(0.5, 1.1), ha='center')

for d in case_data:
    line = ax.plot(theta, d)
    ax.fill(theta, d,  alpha=0.25)
ax.set_varlabels(spoke_labels)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I voted to reopen this question. While the linked script by ImportanceOfBeingEarnest works as expected with Python3.6/matplotlib3.2.2, I also get a different output with Python3.8/matplolib3.3.3 for the inner grid lines.

Comment: So, the problem is in python version? Seems like it works only on python version 3.7 and earlier.

Comment: No, I just have matplotlib 3.2.2 stored in Python3.6. Most likely some matplotlib version changes, maybe how the script hooks `gl.get_path()._interpolation_steps = num_vars` into the renderer. There were some change related to the renderer but I am not familiar with the details.

Comment: @JohanC sorry, I also think that the question should be reopened.

Comment: Yup, downgrading to matplotlib 3.2.2 restores the previous behavior. Something in the upgrade to 3.3.3 has changed how the polar plot gridlines are generated, and now `_interpolation_steps ` is overridden by a standard value. Tbf, the matplotlib documentation says [`This attribute is primarily an implementation detail and is not intended for public use.`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/path_api.html?highlight=matplotlib%20path#module-matplotlib.path)

Comment: Thanks everyone, downgrading matplotlib helped me. How can i put the axes labels by the vertical axis (O1 in my example)?

Comment: `ax.set_rlabel_position(0)` but then it will overlap with the gridline.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My questions are resolved.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this without downgrading matplotlib?

Comment: Only downgrading helped me.

Comment: Did anyone figure out how to do this without downgrading?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment so I'll put this down as an answer.
An update to the code that can serve as a workaround and works on Matplotlib > 3.5 has been recently added to issue 19981 by prohde.
You can check it here:
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/19981

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @joao-neves the docs will be updated in this [PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/22458/files). The working code for your example would be

```py
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, RegularPolygon
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.projections.polar import PolarAxes
from matplotlib.projections import register_projection
from matplotlib.spines import Spine
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D


def radar_factory(num_vars, frame='circle'):
    """Create a radar chart with `num_vars` axes.

    This function creates a RadarAxes projection and registers it.

    Parameters
    ----------
    num_vars : int
        Number of variables for radar chart.
    frame : {'circle' | 'polygon'}
        Shape of frame surrounding axes.

    """
    # calculate evenly-spaced axis angles
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num_vars, endpoint=False)
    
    class RadarTransform(PolarAxes.PolarTransform):
        def transform_path_non_affine(self, path):
            # Paths with non-unit interpolation steps correspond to gridlines,
            # in which case we force interpolation (to defeat PolarTransform's
            # autoconversion to circular arcs).
            if path._interpolation_steps > 1:
                path = path.interpolated(num_vars)
            return Path(self.transform(path.vertices), path.codes)

    class RadarAxes(PolarAxes):

        name = 'radar'
        PolarTransform = RadarTransform

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            # rotate plot such that the first axis is at the top
            self.set_theta_zero_location('N')

        def fill(self, *args, closed=True, **kwargs):
            """Override fill so that line is closed by default"""
            return super().fill(closed=closed, *args, **kwargs)

        def plot(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """Override plot so that line is closed by default"""
            lines = super().plot(*args, **kwargs)
            for line in lines:
                self._close_line(line)

        def _close_line(self, line):
            x, y = line.get_data()
            # FIXME: markers at x[0], y[0] get doubled-up
            if x[0] != x[-1]:
                x = np.concatenate((x, [x[0]]))
                y = np.concatenate((y, [y[0]]))
                line.set_data(x, y)

        def set_varlabels(self, labels):
            self.set_thetagrids(np.degrees(theta), labels)

        def _gen_axes_patch(self):
            # The Axes patch must be centered at (0.5, 0.5) and of radius 0.5
            # in axes coordinates.
            if frame == 'circle':
                return Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.5)
            elif frame == 'polygon':
                return RegularPolygon((0.5, 0.5), num_vars, radius=0.5, edgecolor="k")
            else:
                raise ValueError("unknown value for 'frame': %s" % frame)

        def draw(self, renderer):
            """ Draw. If frame is polygon, make gridlines polygon-shaped """
            if frame == 'polygon':
                gridlines = self.yaxis.get_gridlines()
                for gl in gridlines:
                    gl.get_path()._interpolation_steps = num_vars
            super().draw(renderer)

        def _gen_axes_spines(self):
            if frame == 'circle':
                return super()._gen_axes_spines()
            elif frame == 'polygon':
                # spine_type must be 'left'/'right'/'top'/'bottom'/'circle'.
                spine = Spine(axes=self,
                              spine_type='circle',
                              path=Path.unit_regular_polygon(num_vars))
                # unit_regular_polygon gives a polygon of radius 1 centered at
                # (0, 0) but we want a polygon of radius 0.5 centered at (0.5,
                # 0.5) in axes coordinates.
                spine.set_transform(Affine2D().scale(.5).translate(.5, .5)
                                    + self.transAxes)
                return {'polar': spine}
            else:
                raise ValueError("unknown value for 'frame': %s" % frame)

    register_projection(RadarAxes)
    return theta


data = [['O1', 'O2', 'O3', 'O4', 'O5'],
        ('Title', [
                    [4, 3.5, 4, 2, 3,], 
                    [1.07, 5.95, 2.04, 1.05, 0.00,], 
                  ]
        )]

N = len(data[0])
theta = radar_factory(N, frame='polygon')                                     

spoke_labels = data.pop(0)
title, case_data = data[0]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5), subplot_kw=dict(projection='radar'))
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85, bottom=0.05)
ax.set_rgrids([0, 1, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6])
ax.set_title(title,  position=(0.5, 1.1), ha='center')

for d in case_data:
    line = ax.plot(theta, d)
    ax.fill(theta, d, alpha=0.25, label='_nolegend_')
ax.set_varlabels(spoke_labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]