# How do I change the color of the area inside the lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using python matplotlib and here's my code. I want to change the cyan color inside the lines. How would I go about doing that? Also, if you know how to change the background color, that would also be much appreciated! Thank you, I'm a newbie at this...

Consequently, if you also know how to turn the inner circles into polygons like the outer hexagonal shape, please tell that to me too. Thank you! I've been looking for how to do this change yet nothing came up yet.

```
import os
import RadarGraph
from pprint import pprint
from string import Template

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, RegularPolygon
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.projections.polar import PolarAxes
from matplotlib.projections import register_projection
from matplotlib.spines import Spine
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

def radar_factory(num_vars, frame='circle'):
    """Create a radar chart with `num_vars` axes.

    This function creates a RadarAxes projection and registers it.

    Parameters
    ----------
    num_vars : int
        Number of variables for radar chart.
    frame : {'circle' | 'polygon'}
        Shape of frame surrounding axes.

    """
    # calculate evenly-spaced axis angles
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num_vars, endpoint=False)

    class RadarAxes(PolarAxes):

        name = 'radar'

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            # rotate plot such that the first axis is at the top
            self.set_theta_zero_location('N')

        def fill(self, *args, closed=True, **kwargs):
            """Override fill so that line is closed by default"""
            return super().fill(closed=closed, *args, **kwargs)

        def plot(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """Override plot so that line is closed by default"""
            lines = super().plot(*args, **kwargs)
            for line in lines:
                self._close_line(line)

        def _close_line(self, line):
            x, y = line.get_data()
            # FIXME: markers at x[0], y[0] get doubled-up
            if x[0] != x[-1]:
                x = np.concatenate((x, [x[0]]))
                y = np.concatenate((y, [y[0]]))
                line.set_data(x, y)

        def set_varlabels(self, labels):
            self.set_thetagrids(np.degrees(theta), labels)

        def _gen_axes_patch(self):
            # The Axes patch must be centered at (0.5, 0.5) and of radius 0.5
            # in axes coordinates.
            if frame == 'circle':
                return Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.5)
            elif frame == 'polygon':
                return RegularPolygon((0.5, 0.5), num_vars,
                                      radius=.5, edgecolor="k")
            else:
                raise ValueError("unknown value for 'frame': %s" % frame)

        def draw(self, renderer):
            """ Draw. If frame is polygon, make gridlines polygon-shaped """
            if frame == 'polygon':
                gridlines = self.yaxis.get_gridlines()
                for gl in gridlines:
                    gl.get_path()._interpolation_steps = num_vars
            super().draw(renderer)


        def _gen_axes_spines(self):
            if frame == 'circle':
                return super()._gen_axes_spines()
            elif frame == 'polygon':
                # spine_type must be 'left'/'right'/'top'/'bottom'/'circle'.
                spine = Spine(axes=self,
                              spine_type='circle',
                              path=Path.unit_regular_polygon(num_vars))
                # unit_regular_polygon gives a polygon of radius 1 centered at
                # (0, 0) but we want a polygon of radius 0.5 centered at (0.5,
                # 0.5) in axes coordinates.
                spine.set_transform(Affine2D().scale(.5).translate(.5, .5)
                                    + self.transAxes)


                return {'polar': spine}
            else:
                raise ValueError("unknown value for 'frame': %s" % frame)

    register_projection(RadarAxes)
    return theta



plt.style.use("dark_background")

data = [
    ["Defense", "Damage   ", "Soloing      ", "Farming", "Support", "    Group\n  DPS", "PVP"],
    ("Class Stats",[
        # [5, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 4], #Abyssal
        # [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
        # [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4],
        [6, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4],

        ])

]

N = len(data[0])
theta = RadarGraph.radar_factory(N, frame='circle')

spoke_labels = data.pop(0)
title, case_data = data[0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5.5, 5), subplot_kw=dict(projection='radar'))

fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85, bottom=0.05)

ax.set_rgrids(radii=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], labels=[" ", "D", "C", "B", "A", "S", "SS"], angle=180)
ax.set_title(title,  position=(0.5, 1.1), ha='center')
ax.set_ylim([0,6])
for d in case_data:
    line = ax.plot(theta, d)
    ax.fill(theta, d,  alpha=0.25)
ax.set_varlabels(spoke_labels)

fig.savefig("./demo_.png", transparent=False)
plt.show
```

()

[image: Radar Chart]

Comment: There is an answer on [how to create a polygonal spider chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910187/how-to-make-a-polygon-radar-spider-chart-in-python) but it only [works up to matplotlib 3.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65514398/8881141).

Comment: I see. I finally got it! Thank you so much Mr. T! btw, do the devs plan to return the behavior anytime soon?

Comment: This script by ImportanceOfBeingEarnest utilizes an unsupported feature under the hood. I would not know whether in 3.3.3 the behavior of this component was inadvertently changed and be reverted in future releases or the underlying structure was modified.

Comment: That's okay. Thank you for taking your time to reply Mr. T! :)